# How to subset a Polygon layer to only polygons that border a multiline feature

Tags: r, mapping, gis

I have a layer of polygon features representing land parcels over a large tract of area, and a  mulipoint line segment representing a river.  I would like to snip the polygon layer to only those that border the river.  I have tried st_intersect, but that only returns an empty matrix.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your river data separate from you main data? 
I think that the solution may be with `sf::st_geometry_type()`. After, you can filter as if you would do with normal data.  If the rivers and the polygon is in the same data, the solution includes `sf::st_intersection()` as well.

Feel free to share more details on how your data is structured.

Comment: it's in two separate dataframes, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Ok, I'd recommend reading https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/spatial-operations.html#topological-relations. If you could share a sample of your data, it would be easier to help. It is possible that your river is not contained fully, 

``sf::st_filter(polygon, river, .predicate = sf::st_touches)``

Comment: so @olivroy thank you for the great reference.  I've kind of only slowly picked up bits and pieces of GIS in R while finding out how to do what I need to do.  I will definitely read that to bolster my foundation, as there are clearly key pieces missing judging by the simplicity of this answer.  Polygon[st_buffer(River, dist = 25),] did exactly what I needed it to do.  Thank you!